# glibc detected, memory issue

Tags: ros, sicklms, memory

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am using the [lms1xx](https://github.com/clearpathrobotics/LMS1xx) driver to read data from a LMS100 laser. I am using ROS hydro.
Could someone help me to solve this issue.

```
[ INFO] [1428468323.403817484]: connecting to laser at : 192.168.0.1
[ INFO] [1428468323.404342624]: Connected to laser.
*** glibc detected *** /home/intern/catkin_ws/devel/lib/lms1xx/LMS1xx_node_faux: free(): invalid next size (normal): 0x0922a368 ***
======= Backtrace: =========
/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(+0x75232)[0xb72d7232]
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6(_ZdlPv+0x18)[0xb7499d38]
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6(_ZdaPv+0x18)[0xb7499d98]
/home/intern/catkin_ws/devel/lib/lms1xx/LMS1xx_node_faux(_ZN5boost20checked_array_deleteIhEEvPT_+0x17)[0x8055d1f]
/home/intern/catkin_ws/devel/lib/lms1xx/LMS1xx_node_faux(_ZNK5boost21checked_array_deleterIhEclEPh+0x11)[0x805554d]
/home/intern/catkin_ws/devel/lib/lms1xx/LMS1xx_node_faux(_ZN5boost6detail18sp_counted_impl_pdIPhNS_21checked_array_deleterIhEEE7disposeEv+0x1e)[0x80572ee]
/opt/ros/hydro/lib/libroscpp.so(_ZN3ros10Connection14writeTransportEv+0x518)[0xb768aa78]
/opt/ros/hydro/lib/libroscpp.so(_ZN3ros10Connection11onWriteableERKN5boost10shared_ptrINS_9TransportEEE+0x1b)[0xb768b54b]
/opt/ros/hydro/lib/libroscpp.so(_ZN5boost6detail8function26void_function_obj_invoker1INS_3_bi6bind_tIvNS_4_mfi3mf1IvN3ros10ConnectionERKNS_10shared_ptrINS7_9TransportEEEEENS3_5list2INS3_5valueIPS8_EENS_3argILi1EEEEEEEvSD_E6invokeERNS1_15function_bufferESD_+0x29)[0xb768d099]
/opt/ros/hydro/lib/libroscpp.so(_ZN3ros12TransportTCP12socketUpdateEi+0x1c9)[0xb76e87f9]
/opt/ros/hydro/lib/libroscpp.so(_ZN5boost6detail8function26void_function_obj_invoker1INS_3_bi6bind_tIvNS_4_mfi3mf1IvN3ros12TransportTCPEiEENS3_5list2INS3_5valueIPS8_EENS_3argILi1EEEEEEEviE6invokeERNS1_15function_bufferEi+0x29)[0xb76ea1b9]
/opt/ros/hydro/lib/libroscpp.so(_ZN3ros7PollSet6updateEi+0x358)[0xb7718098]
/opt/ros/hydro/lib/libroscpp.so(_ZN3ros11PollManager10threadFuncEv+0xdd)[0xb76bd2fd]
/opt/ros/hydro/lib/libroscpp.so(_ZN5boost6detail11thread_dataINS_3_bi6bind_tIvNS_4_mfi3mf0IvN3ros11PollManagerEEENS2_5list1INS2_5valueIPS7_EEEEEEE3runEv+0x2b)[0xb76bd43b]
/usr/lib/libboost_thread.so.1.46.1(thread_proxy+0x6c)[0xb724848c]
/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0(+0x6d4c)[0xb75a0d4c]
/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(clone+0x5e)[0xb7350fde]
======= Memory map: ========
08048000-0805c000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 7486784    /home/intern/catkin_ws/devel/lib/lms1xx/LMS1xx_node_faux
0805c000-0805d000 r--p 00013000 08:01 7486784    /home/intern/catkin_ws/devel/lib/lms1xx/LMS1xx_node_faux
0805d000-0805e000 rw-p 00014000 08:01 7486784    /home/intern/catkin_ws/devel/lib/lms1xx/LMS1xx_node_faux
09213000-09238000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0          [heap]
b3100000-b3121000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
b3121000-b3200000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
b32fe000-b32ff000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
b32ff000-b3aff000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
b3aff000-b3b00000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
b3b00000-b4300000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
b4300000-b4321000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
b4321000-b4400000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
b4400000-b4421000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
b4421000-b4500000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
b4500000-b4521000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
b4521000-b4600000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
b4665000-b4666000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
b4666000-b4e66000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
b4e66000-b4e67000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
b4e67000-b5667000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
b5667000-b5672000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 524660     /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libnss_files-2.15.so
b5672000-b5673000 r--p 0000a000 08:01 524660     /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libnss_files-2.15.so
b5673000-b5674000 rw-p 0000b000 08:01 524660     /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libnss_files-2.15.so
b569a000-b56a4000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
b56a4000-b56ab000 r--s 00000000 08:01 8921368    /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/gconv/gconv-modules.cache
b56ab000-b579a000 r--p 00857000 08:01 8920146    /usr/lib/locale/locale-archive
b579a000-b599a000 r--p 00000000 08:01 8920146    /usr/lib/locale/locale-archive
b599a000-b59a1000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
b59a1000-b6b10000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 8920221    /usr/lib/libicudata.so.48.1.1
b6b10000-b6b11000 r--p 0116e000 08:01 8920221    /usr/lib/libicudata.so.48.1.1
b6b11000-b6b12000 rw-p 0116f000 08:01 8920221    /usr/lib/libicudata.so.48.1.1
b6b12000-b6b15000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 527578     /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libdl-2.15.so
b6b15000-b6b16000 r--p 00002000 08:01 527578     /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libdl-2.15.so
b6b16000-b6b17000 rw-p 00003000 08:01 527578     /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libdl-2.15.so
b6b17000-b6b1b000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 524352     /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libuuid.so.1.3.0
b6b1b000-b6b1c000 r--p 00003000 08:01 524352     /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libuuid.so.1.3.0
b6b1c000-b6b1d000 rw-p 00004000 08:01 524352     /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libuuid.so.1.3.0
b6b1d000-b6b43000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 524314     /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libexpat.so.1.5.2
b6b43000-b6b44000 ---p 00026000 08:01 524314     /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libexpat.so.1.5.2
b6b44000-b6b46000 r--p 00026000 08:01 524314     /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libexpat.so.1.5.2
b6b46000-b6b47000 rw-p 00028000 08:01 524314     /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libexpat.so.1.5.2
b6b47000-b6b48000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
b6b48000-b6b50000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 527577     /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libcrypt-2.15.so
b6b50000-b6b51000 r--p 00007000 08:01 527577     /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libcrypt-2.15.so
b6b51000-b6b52000 rw-p 00008000 08:01 527577     /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libcrypt-2.15.so
b6b52000-b6b79000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
b6b79000-b6d45000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 8920219    /usr/lib/libicui18n.so.48.1.1
b6d45000-b6d46000 ---p 001cc000 08:01 8920219    /usr/lib/libicui18n.so.48.1.1
b6d46000-b6d4c000 r--p 001cc000 08:01 8920219    /usr/lib/libicui18n.so.48.1.1
b6d4c000-b6d4d000 rw-p 001d2000 08:01 8920219    /usr/lib/libicui18n.so.48.1.1
b6d4d000-b6d4e000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
b6d4e000-b6ea3000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 8920213    /usr/lib/libicuuc.so.48.1.1
b6ea3000-b6ead000 r--p 00155000 08:01 8920213    /usr/lib/libicuuc.so.48.1.1
b6ead000-b6eae000 rw-p 0015f000 08:01 8920213    /usr/lib/libicuuc.so.48.1.1
b6eae000-b6eb2000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
b6eb2000-b6ee5000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 8929347    /usr/lib/libapr-1.so.0.4.6
b6ee5000-b6ee6000 r--p 00032000 08:01 8929347    /usr/lib/libapr-1.so.0.4.6
b6ee6000-b6ee7000 rw-p 00033000 08:01 8929347    /usr/lib/libapr-1.so.0.4.6
b6ee7000-b6f08000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 8929409    /usr/lib/libaprutil-1.so.0.3.12
b6f08000-b6f09000 r--p 00020000 08:01 8929409    /usr/lib/libaprutil-1.so.0.3.12
b6f09000-b6f0a000 rw-p 00021000 08:01 8929409    /usr/lib/libaprutil-1.so.0.3.12
b6f0a000-b6f0b000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
b6f0b000-b6f12000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 525006     /lib/i386-linux-gnu/librt-2.15.so
b6f12000-b6f13000 r--p 00006000 08:01 525006     /lib/i386-linux-gnu/librt-2.15.so
b6f13000-b6f14000 rw-p 00007000 08:01 525006     /lib/i386-linux-gnu/librt-2.15.so
Aborted (core dumped)
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/206839/glibc-detected,-memory-issue/) by [vince](https://answers.ros.org/users/21818/vince/) on ROS Answers with karma: 26 on 2015-04-08

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Yes I did but I don't remember exactly which one is the good solution.
First be sure you installed this one :
http://wiki.ros.org/LMS1xx
Then you have to change the settings of the laser, for that you use the software given by SICK and set to 0.5°the angle between each beam and the frequency to 25Hz.
And if it is still not working wait for the laser to be "initialized" by waiting that the red light in front stop to flash.

---

Originally posted by [vince](https://answers.ros.org/users/21818/vince/) with karma: 26 on 2015-07-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0